# Correct handling of async Mongo actions in Node Promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

I have a function which performs multiple Mongo actions, and the last action is to close the database after all other actions have completed. I was fairly confident of my handling of the issue, but I have had some external comments raise concerns, and I wanted to verify if my solution is correct.

**A suggested solution:**

```
function updateDatabase (name, token) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL)
      .then( (database) => {
          return database.collection('testCollection').update({name}, {$pull: {tokens: {$in: [token]}}})
            .then( () => {
              database.collection('log').insert({
                name,
                token
              });
              return database;
            })
      })
      .then( (db) => {
        db.close(true);
        resolve(`Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`);
      })
      .catch( (err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
  });
}
```

**My original solution:**

```
function updateDatabase (name, token) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL)
      .then( (database) => {
        return database;
      })
      .then( (db) => {
        database.collection('testCollection').update({name}, {$pull: {tokens: {$in: [token]}}})
        return database;
      })
      .then( () => {
        database.collection('log').insert({
          name,
          token
        });
        return database;
      })
      .then( (db) => {
        db.close(true);
        resolve(`Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`);
      })
      .catch( (err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
  });
}
```

Is my original solution way off the mark or is the suggested solution a better approach? Both work in testing but against a production grade load, I need to make sure the db does not close until other actions are complete, which I believe I have accomplished in my original solution.

Comment: Are you asking if one of the two will close the connection before completing the operations? If so, I don't think they would if you say they're both passing the tests you have, assuming the tests are good. Or are you asking for a style comparison? A performance comparison?

Comment: Both implementations are lacking: wrapping code that is promise-based with a `new Promise` is an anti-pattern, there's no proper error checking (although the proposed solution is a _bit_ better), and the database doesn't get closed in the `catch` handler.

Comment: @TW80000 I am asking if one of the two will close the connection before completing the operations? My tests are not load tests or performance tests, just tests to check that the updates have occurred and that the db closes after.

Comment: @robertklep, that is a good point. Maybe I should remove the return new Promise, and just perform the MongoClient operations, which will return a promise object anyway?

Comment: @jmcgui05 I'm no expert, but if the connection was closing before the updates complete, then your tests to make sure that the updates happened would be failing, right? Since they're not failing, can't you conclude that the connection is closing after the operation and therefore your code is working properly? It certainly looks correct to me (other than the wrapped promise that robertklep mentioned).

Comment: @TW80000 My worry is that incorrectly handled async code can appear to work correctly until under a heavy load. So, while my local dev tests pass, I am not yet fully convinced that this will behave the same in a prod environment. I'm no expert either, but the reason I asked the question in the first place is that the suggested solution, nesting promises, looks like heading back to callback hell type of code.

Comment: The question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all asynchronous operations of the MongoDB driver already return a promise, you shouldn't use `new Promise` at all, but set up a promise chain:

```
function updateDatabase(name, token) {
  let database;
  return MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL).then(db => {
    database = db;
    return database
      .collection("testCollection")
      .update({ name }, { $pull: { tokens: { $in: [token] } } });
  })
  .then(() => {
    return database.collection("log").insert({
      name,
      token
    });
  })
  .then(() => {
    database.close(true);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    database.close(true);
    throw err;
  });
}
```

I understand that you want to pass `database` as an argument for the next `then`, but you'll run into the issue that it won't be available in the `catch` handler. One solution is to use a function-scoped variable that gets assigned after opening the connection, like the code above does.

If you don't like that, you can create a new promise chain inside the `.then` handler for `MongoClient.connect`:

```
function updateDatabase(name, token) {
  return MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL).then(database => {
    return database
      .collection("testCollection")
      .update({ name }, { $pull: { tokens: { $in: [token] } } })
      .then(() => {
        return database.collection("log").insert({
          name,
          token
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        database.close(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        database.close(true);
        throw err;
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to outline some major problems with the original code:

```
function updateDatabase (name, token) {
  //useless. MongoClient.connect already returns the promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL)
      .then( (database) => {
        // useless. The function does nothing and can be removed
        return database;  
      })
      .then( (db) => {
        // should be db, not database
        // update is async. Should be added to the chain.
        database.collection('testCollection').update({name}, {$pull: {tokens: {$in: [token]}}})
        // what's the point to return database, if the following function does not accept any parameters
        return database;
      })      
      .then( () => {
        // insert is async. Should be added to the chain.
        database.collection('log').insert({
          name,
          token
        });
        return database;
      })
      .then( (db) => {
        // close is async. Should be added to the chain.
        db.close(true);
        resolve(`Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`);
      })
      .catch( (err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
  });
}
```

So the function should really look like:

```
function updateDatabase (name, token) {
    return MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL)
      .then( db => 
        db.collection('testCollection').update({name}, {$pull: {tokens: {$in: [token]}}})
          .then(()=>db)
      })      
      .then( db => 
        db.collection('log').insert({name, token})
          .then(()=>db)
      })
      .then( db => db.close(true))
      .then(()=>`Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`);
}
```

And if the order of queries doesn't matter, you can benefit from `Promise.all`:

```
function updateDatabase (name, token) {
    return MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL)
      .then( db => Promise.all([
        Promise.resolve(db),
        db.collection('testCollection').update({name}, {$pull: {tokens: {$in: [token]}}}),
        db.collection('log').insert({name, token}),
      ])
      .then( ([db]) => db.close(true))
      .then(()=>`Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The common problem of both solutions is .then(function) handler. Instead of returning Promise for MongoDB operation, handler returns database, therefore next chain handler will be called not waiting for MongoDB operation to complete. Instead Promises for MongoDB operations should be chained in order of execution. Also Mongo methods return Promise, so no need for new Promise:

```
function updateDatabase (name, token) {
  return MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL)
     .then( (db) => 
          Promise.all([
            db.collection('testCollection').update({name}, {$pull: {tokens: {$in: [token]}}}),
            db.collection('log').insert({name, token})
          ]).then(() => db.close(true)
          ).then(`Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`
          ).catch((err) => { db.close(true); throw err });
     )
}
```

or with async/await syntax:

```
async function updateDatabase (name, token) {
    let db = await MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL);
    try {
      await db.collection('testCollection').update({name}, {$pull: {tokens: {$in: [token]}}});
      await db.collection('log').insert({name, token});
      return `Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`;
    } finally { 
      await db.close(true);
    }
}
```