# Trouble with node, mongodb, and promises

Tags: javascript, mongodb, callback, promise, nested

I have working code that uses a series of nested callbacks to first check the database for a pre-existing entry with  a find command.  If the entry exists, do nothing.  If the entry does not exist, insert one into the db.

This code works well but provides no meaningful error handling:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/peeps", function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            if(db) db.close();
            return next();
        }
        var query = { section: req.body.section, year: req.body.year, semester: req.body.semester };
            db.collection("sections").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {

            if( result.length >= 1  ) {
                db.close();
                if(callback) callback();
            } else {
                var days = [];

                for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

                    if( field['starthour' + i]  != '') {
                        var oneDay = {};
                        oneDay.day = field['day' + i];
                        // more fields being stored here...
                        days.push(oneDay);

                    }
                }

                db.collection("sections").insertOne(
                    { 
                        coursetitle: req.body.course,
                        // more fields being stored here
                        days: days
                    }
                )
                db.close();
                if(callback) callback();
            }
        })
    })
```

Enter promises, a supposed fix for callback hell and error handling. So the first problem that I have with promises (and I have searched and tried every single post with the keywords Mongodb, promise, node, and find) is how to still avoid nesting promises.

Here is one way of MANY different ways I tried to implement a Promise strategy:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/peeps")
        .then(function(db) {
            var query = { section: req.body.section, year: req.body.year, semester: req.body.semester };
            db.collection("sections").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
                // I am assuming that returns from this callback won't return to the next .then statement...
                // how to avoid nesting promises?
                // If a nested promise is necessary, how do I set it up?  .find does not seem to return a promise... (I've tried)
                if(err) return err; // Where does it go?  probably not to the catch statement like I want it to :-(
                if(result.length >= 1)
                    return {db: db, preexist: true};
                else {
                    return {db: db, preexist: false};
                }
            })
        })
        .then(function(o){
            // o didn't make it here, so db doesn't exist nor preexist, they're undefined
            console.log(o.db + o.preexist)
            // do the insert one if necessary
        })      
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        })
```

So in essence my major issues are:  How to avoid nesting?  If nesting promises is necessary, is there a way to return errors to the outermost .catch?  Does .find return a promise if no callback is specified?  If .find can return a promise, what is the proper syntax for storing the result in an array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your first .then has no return, which is why o in the second then is undefined

Comment: Two options, wrap the `db.collection("sections").find(query).toArray` code in a Promise, or, if the documentation is correct, `toArray` returns a Promise anyway, so use that. However, there will always be some level of nesting when you want to pass on variables down the .then chain

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB just like most other DB *providers* offers a method to retrieve the most recent error.

For MongoDB you would use `db.getLastError()` to retrieve the error object/document. [Here are the fields you can use from that document.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getLastError/#dbcmd.getLastError)

From a more abstract perspective the way you structure your promises depends on the data model itself, the logic of your application, and the amount of caching you can do safely.

The way you perform *chaining* of promises can be achieved using the **Promise.all** method and a collection of DB operations without the need for multiple .then() statements and/or unnecessary DB connections:

```
function updateDatabase (name, token) {
  return MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL)
     .then( (db) => 
          Promise.all([
            db.collection('testCollection').update({name}, {$pull: {tokens: {$in: [token]}}}),
            db.collection('log').insert({name, token})
          ]).then(() => db.close(true)
          ).then(`Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`
          ).catch((err) => { db.close(true); throw err }); //catch errors
     )
}
```

[More information in here: from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845982/1848744](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845982/1848744)

Comment: *.then(`Invalid token: ${token} has been removed from: ${name}`)* - no, not valid - wont break, but what purpose do you think that serves?